# Organising Classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

i am currently creating an app in eclipse (ADK) and i have a lot of xml files and java classes.  Is there any way i can sort them into relavent folders or packages?

as an example, i have 6 classes that are student related, 4 classes that are teacher related, and 7 classes that are parent related.  Currently, they are all stored in the same package in a long list, which is hard to read, i want to sort it, so that each three groups of classes are contained in a seperate space or folder.

Comment: Create the packages, and drag and drop the classes into them. Or right-click once a class or several ones are selected, and choose Refactor - Move.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may create 3 folders under the main package named as `Students`, `Teachers` and `Parents`. After that, place the classes relative to their folders.